# Google Maps, Rails and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

**Update 7/17 SOLVED**

I've updated my code to the Solved version.

***Original Question***

I'm trying to show Google Maps via the Gem gmaps4rails. After researching the following 2 questions that were posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229274/gmaps4rails-shows-just-half-of-the-map-when-iside-tab-any-idea-why?rq=1) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014156/google-maps-and-jquery-tabs) it seems Google Maps has issues with a tab that hides and shows content from Jquery or Javascript and will not display a Google Map properly without some code in the Jquery.

I'm stuck on resizing the map in my javascript can someone point out my errors?

Thanks!

My code:

**Javascript**

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Default Action
    $(".gear_tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.gear_page_tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".gear_tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    $(".map_container").hide(); //Hide the Google Map

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.gear_page_tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.gear_page_tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".gear_tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    if(activeTab == '#GearLocation') {  
        $(".map_container").show();             
            Gmaps.loadMaps();
            Gmaps.map.addMarkers(json);
            google.maps.event.trigger(Gmaps.map, 'resize');

     }
     return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

**My View**

```
<div id="GearLocation" class="gear_tab_content">    
    <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
</div><!-- End GearLocation -->
```

**Controller**

```
  def show
    @gear = Gear.find(params[:id])
    @storegear = @gear.user.gears.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 6)
    @comments = @gear.comments.all
    @user = @gear.user
    @store = @gear.user.store.id
    @json = @gear.to_gmaps4rails
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @json }
    end   
  end
```

**Routes**

```
       gears GET    /gears(.:format)                             gears#index
                 POST   /gears(.:format)                             gears#create
        new_gear GET    /gears/new(.:format)                         gears#new
       edit_gear GET    /gears/:id/edit(.:format)                    gears#edit
            gear GET    /gears/:id(.:format)                         gears#show
                 PUT    /gears/:id(.:format)                         gears#update
                 DELETE /gears/:id(.:format)                         gears#destroy
                        /gear(.:format)                              gears#index
```

Thanks Again.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1643990

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on that code...could you elaborate on how I might implement that? For example ...Should the ".map_container" be the actual div or other container the map is in or should that be the map_container that is in your Gem? Should I remove my other javascript that is hiding that content? Etc....thanks I'm a newbie and I don't code javascript a lot.

Comment: I've updated my code...what am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you show/hide/resize a google maps map you need to call the resize event of the map.
Soyou should add it after showing it:

```
...
Gmaps.map.addMarkers(json);
google.maps.event.trigger(Gmaps.map, 'resize');
...
```

I'm assuming that Gmaps.map is an instance of google.maps.Map class...

Comment: Iwiznia, My map is not showing up at all when I try using apneadiving's code from his Gem. I'm kind of stuck.. I've updated my code to reflect how it is now.

Comment: It looks like the call is gmaps4rails(@json). Then you should give the div containing the map a width and height on css. I don't know that gem so I don't how to pass the gem the width and height options to the google maps api.

Comment: That still is not working even after assigning the div a width and height. The code you suggested for the call is the code that I originally started with in my view and changed it based on apneadiving's comment. The gem is Google-Maps-for-Rails https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails